# How to set the PCH value for geom_point as part of a theme element in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Background:

I'm trying to create a customized theme in ggplot2 that I can engrave using my laser engraver. I've found a few different things that work well such as this color pallet, and using a aspect ration that is the same size as the plaque. When I use colors that are white, or near white it works best to have a outline around the points so they are easy to distinguish on the plaque. I've found that pch=21, works very well for this.

Question:

How do I set the pch value as part of my theme_engrave theme in ggplot2?

Below is a not perfect minimalist example:

```
theme_engrave = function(){
  engrave_colors = c("#000000","#303030","#ADADAD","#FAFAFA","#FFFFFF")

  #update_geom_defaults("point", list(pch = 21)) 
  ## This is a bad idea, since it changes the pch for more than just the theme.  

  theme_bw() %+replace%
    theme(
  aspect.ratio=7/9,
#What should go here to set the PCH default value for geom_point(pch=21)
  )
}
```

This ends the theme part. But we need to still see the plot.

```
mtcarsPlot = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, fill=as.factor(cyl)))+
        geom_point(pch=21, color='black')+labs(title='MT Cars MPG Vs HP by Engine Cylinders')+
        scale_fill_manual(values =engrave_colors)+labs() +theme_engrave()
mtcarsPlot
```

What I've tried:

if I just add: pch=21 in the theme, I get:

`` Error: Theme element `pch` is not defined in the element hierarchy. ``
I've also tried using shape=21, in the theme, and am unable to get it to work.

I don't want to change the default behavior of pch by using

```update_geom_defaults("point", list(pch = 21))```

because it changes it for all future charts even when not using my theme.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Package `ggthemes` solves the problem by defining shape palettes and `scale_*` layers.